# FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() returns a Location that has isFromMockProvider() to false even if it comes from a mock provider

Tags: google-play-services

I'm sorry, this is not really a question but an observation :).

Since I can't find a bugtracker for Play Services, and it's my understanding that the Play Services team monitor this tag, this is my only hope.

We're trying to avoid mock locations in our app, and this is preventing us from doing so.

This is reproducible very easily with the 'Fake GPS' app.

Comment: You can try posting this to Google Sample - [android-play-location](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues), this might help you since many developers also check this sample related to Play location. Hope this helps.